# PyTest import error while attempting to use parallel testing

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to do parallel testing using PyTest. Also I am using unittest and stickng to Page Object Pattern. The error I keep running into is:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Automation\Test\Scripts\test_AccountCreation.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
Test\Scripts\test_ArtistAccountCreation.py:1: in <module>
    from Automation.Test.TestBase.EnvironmentSetUp import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Automation'
```

The missing module "Automation' is the folder name in which I keep the project files.

```
from Automation.Test.TestBase.EnvironmentSetUp import *
```

This is an import line from the test script, there is a class with SetUp and tearDown modules in the file.

Comment: Does your `%username%` in the path contain some special characters?

Comment: it does contain a '.' ( dot ). Could this be the reason?

Comment: is Automation a folder or a module. I mean check if all the folders has `__init__.py` file

Comment: Automation is a folder. I've eliminated all special characters from the path today and it did not work.